# Responsive solution for HTML dropdown selects

Tags: css, forms, responsive-design

I'm looking for a responsive solution for dropdown lists.

[image: Normal]

[image: Ipad]

First image is normal, second is on an iPad.

Unfortunately my list falls outside of it's container on tablets. I've thought of changing the font size but it is quite small already and I don't want to make the font any smaller

EDIT: Link provided

http://hub.yfish.co.uk/testing/BEST/root-final/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try Bootstrap form elements : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes. Might be what you are looking for.

Comment: To be honest your site isnt really being properly responsive in the way it should be, I would recommend making all the elements in `.action-profile` 100% width for smaller devices

Comment: that will solve your issue of the select dropdown going over the element

Comment: Why don't you just give the select a width of 100% through a css class?

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the fast replies - my site only responds down to 768 and yes it's a bit rocky! Will sift through your answers and update here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap (like I am) make sure you check the documentation (like I should have) as it has everything you would need!

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes

Adding the class .form-control solved my problem